# eliminate weekend dates by shifting it on work dates

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a worksheet in which there is some work that has to be done on any specific date monthly, weekly, quarterly, yearly and daily. I have a formula that auto shows the planned date on which any work has to be done. But there is a need for change in formula that I have only taken all the dates from Monday to Saturday as Sunday is off here.

The problem arises here. please see C13, D13, E13, date of December (12/8/2019) is Sunday. (please see FT13:FW13). so I want that if Sunday falls on any planned date it should roll over to Monday automatically. for example, if 12/8/2019 is sunday this should show up the planned date automatically in cell FV13 (12/9/2019) which is Monday. it means date should be auto roll from Sunday to Monday. however, I have got a formula that can round up the Sunday for monthly planned works. (you can see E12 ,FT12:FW12)  but round up of dates is still needed for yearly and quarterly planned works.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CXjQDjiP_xTnb8DcpsgQKmLyaaV9XX0NdisvcruuOfY/edit#gid=1924994592

Comment: how do you get those dates in E column? I dont see any formula for that

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do `IF` statement to correct the weekend dates acordingly:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", 
 IF(TEXT(A2:A, "ddd")="Sat", A2:A+2, 
 IF(TEXT(A2:A, "ddd")="Sun", A2:A+1, A2:A)), ))
```

[image: 0]